# Pandas: can't drop columns: ValueError: labels [<colName>] not contained in axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a df created from a simple CSV.  When I try to reference columns by their names, to merge into a new df or to drop, I am getting a

```
ValueError: labels [<colName>] not contained in axis
```

I understand that to drop a column you must use

```
axis=1
```

It's as if somehow the df is confused that my columns are the columns, even though they are the top row and bolded when viewed in iPython.

Comment: You should add the exact code you are using and an example of the data, (without compromising any personal info obviously)

Comment: I think maybe there are some white space before or after the column names.

Comment: If you spelled the columns correctly (case sensitive) and it's still not being recognized, there is white space that you're missing, as suggested by @HYRY

Comment: Posting the symptoms or errors without accompanying data and code to reproduce the error is counter-productive as it becomes a guessing game. Please post sample and code to reproduce the error. Check your column names `df.columns.tolist()` to see if there any white spaces in there

Answer (score 0):

index it first.

```
df.index = df[colName]
```

Comment: Hi!  Would you please expand a bit more your answer? I didn't get it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found to drop columns is like this:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['col_name_1', 'col_name_2'])
```